# Why I can`t change my colleague`s gulp code?

Tags: html, css, gulp

I just started learning layout, so I have one issue i can`t solve. I work with my colleague on project, he decided to use gulp so i want to work in the same conditions. My steps:

1. Cloned project from github;
2. Installed gulp in main project`s folder via npm i gulp -g;
3. I got working tasks and all installed dependenies my colleague uses;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDnXs.png)

Problem: but i can`t change anything in layout(HTML/CSS/JS). I think solution somewhere in gulpfile.js.

If you give even a small hint, i would be really thankful to you.

```
> D:\SiteRB\Finals4\Altima>gulp default [11:21:47] Using gulpfile
> D:\SiteRB\Finals4\Altima\gulpfile.js [11:21:47] Starting 'default'...
> [11:21:47] Starting 'watch'... [11:21:47] Starting 'server'...
> [11:21:47] Starting 'styles'... [Browsersync] Access URLs: 
> --------------------------------------
>        Local: http://localhost:3000
>     External: http://192.168.0.108:3000  --------------------------------------
>           UI: http://localhost:3001  UI External: http://localhost:3001  --------------------------------------
> [Browsersync] Serving files from: src [Browsersync] 1 file changed
> (style.min.css) [11:21:48] Finished 'styles' after 830 ms
```

Comment: `npm i gulp -g` will install gulp version 4, that gulp file (which you should have included as text, not an image) is written for gulp 3. Not sure if the new CLI is backwards compatible with the old stuff.

Comment: You should also include what the gulp command outputs when you run it, that would help a lot to narrow this down.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, sorry i am bad at navigating this site. As you said i edited with gulp command output

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, according to your first comment now i should get back to older version?

Comment: By that output it seems that it is working with the newer version. It identified the tasks and  started a dev-server on http://localhost:3000. If you make any changes to a scss/sass file, doesn't it then also log "x files changed"?

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, no, it doesn`t. I want to try install older version like npm install -g gulp@3.8.8 or another version

Comment: Any 3.x version should  be fine, I haven't used gulp 3 in a long time though.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, but according to my colleague`s package.json he uses gulp 4.0.2

Comment: Huh, maybe that syntax works with 4.x as well. Then I guess there is something else going on here because otherwise the gulpfile seems fine.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren, i found out what caused this problem. There was a node_modules folder in my colleague`s github. So i deleted this one and installed gulp again. And it works fine. So, anyway, thank you for your help